# How should I organise these build types and flavors?

Tags: android-build, android-productflavors

I'm developing an app and I have to package it for two companies and two environments. Each environment has a host:

- **Test** where HOST is "hostTest"
- **Production** where HOST is "hostProd"

Each company has a URL for each environment:

- **Company 1** where URL is:

  - If *Test* then HOST + PATH_TEST else
  - If *Production* then HOST + PATH_PRODUCTION
- **Company 2** where URL is:

  - If *Test* then HOST + PATH_TEST else
  - If *Production* then HOST + PATH_PRODUCTION

So far, I have two build types:

```
buildTypes {
    test {
        buildConfigField 'String', `HOST`, '"hostTest"' 
    }
    production {
        buildConfigField 'String', `HOST`, '"hostProd"'
    }
}
```

and two product flavors:

```
    company1 {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'PATH_PROD', '"pathC1Prod"' 
        buildConfigField 'String', 'PATH_TEST', '"pathC1Test"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'URL', "???" // if BuildType.BUILD_TYPE == test then HOST + PATH_TEST else HOST + PATH_PROD
    }

    company2 {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'PATH_PROD', '"pathC2Prod"' 
        buildConfigField 'String', 'PATH_TEST', '"pathC2Test"'
        //same as above
    }
```

I hope you understand.

My goal is to get the URL just like:

```
String url = BuildConfig.URL;
```

How can achieve this?